# Adding class objects stored in vector using operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

EDIT: OK, being completely confused by what I actually needed to do and the fact that I didn't want to put specifics, it got too confusing, so I am re-writing my question. Thank you everyone who tried to help.

I have a `class Something` that has `char a, float b, float c`. The values are being read in from a file and stored as a `vector <Something> vec`. I would like to add the objects and display the sum in the end.

How would I go about doing that?

as a more specific example, that actually relates to what I am doing:
I have a `class Force` that holds `char type, float xArg, float yArg`. The values are read in from a file and stored in a `vector <Force> f`. I need to find a sum of all of the forces in that vector and display the result.

Hope this is better

Comment: `accumulate` from STL and maybe another algorithm from `<algorithm>` ?

Comment: How or why do you "know" you need to overload an operator?

Comment: @NickyC should've said "I would like to do that using operator overloading"

Comment: @Ana do you have a reason for _liking `operator+`_?  That seems unintuitive for a task that doesn't involve summing the class itself.

Comment: Why would you like to do that using operator overloading? How or why do you think it is a suitable solution?

Comment: When you say you want to use `operator+` what are the argument types and what is the return type?

Comment: @NickyC , honestly, because I got confused over what i was meant to be doing and didn't word the question right. Completely my bad, in this case operator overloading is indeed not needed, but for what i am actually trying to do I believe it is, should i post a different question or edit this one? Sorry about that, rather new in all of this

Comment: I think an edit would be fine. And I also think it is a perfect opportunity to share with you the term ["XY Problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @NickyC thank you, a very good read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with a custom accumulator:

```
std::accumulate(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), 0.f,
                [](auto acc, auto const& something) {
                    return acc + something.b;
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `std::accumulate`, you can iterate over the items of `vec` and accumulate the values from the items.

```
double sum = 0;
for(auto& item : vec )
{
   sum += item.b;
}
```